# How can I return a custom HTTP status code from a WCF REST method?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

If something goes wrong in a WCF REST call, such as the requested resource is not found, how can I play with the HTTP response code (setting it to something like HTTP 404, for example) in my OperationContract method?

Comment: ok all the answers to this assume control made it into your service implementation. what if they pass some totally invalid uri? how are you suppose to provide a 404 for all the unexpected hits to your service?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

There is a [`WebOperationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.weboperationcontext.aspx) that you can access and it has a [`OutgoingResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.weboperationcontext.outgoingresponse.aspx) property of type [`OutgoingWebResponseContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.outgoingwebresponsecontext.aspx) which has a [`StatusCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.outgoingwebresponsecontext.statuscode.aspx) property that can be set.

```
WebOperationContext ctx = WebOperationContext.Current;
ctx.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
```

Comment: Does this work inside WCF Data Services - Service Operations ? I haven't had luck, seems the StatusCode I set gets trumped by something else.  So on all HTTP POST requests, I get back 204 regardless that I set it at 201,etc.

Comment: Doesn't work in my case, the status gets overwritten. Throwing a `WebFaultException`, however, does seem to work.

Answer (score 78):

If you need to return a reason body then have a look at [WebFaultException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd989924.aspx)

For example

```
throw new WebFaultException<string>("Bar wasn't Foo'd", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest );
```

Comment: I like this better than the accepted one since we are not using the static WebOperationContext.Current

Comment: keep in mind this is only valid since famework 4 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd989924.aspx

Comment: hmm, in .NET 4.5.1 this is not setting the status code for me, I'm still getting a 200. I'm using jsonp, it's calling my callback (in javascript) and passing my message and my status code as an integer.

Comment: This seems great for anything outside of the 2XX codes, but would you throw a `WebFaultException` to return an `HttpStatusCode.Created`?

Answer (score 25):

For 404 there is a built in method on the **WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse** called **SetStatusAsNotFound(string message)** that will set the status code to 404 and a status description with one call.

Note there is also, **SetStatusAsCreated(Uri location)** that will set the status code to 201 and location header with one call.

Comment: Is this preferred over the method displayed in the accepted answer?

Answer (score 7):

You can also return a statuscode and reason body with [WebOperationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.web.weboperationcontext?view=netframework-4.7.2)'s [StatusCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.web.outgoingwebresponsecontext.statuscode?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [StatusDescription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.web.outgoingwebresponsecontext.statusdescription?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
WebOperationContext context = WebOperationContext.Current;
context.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
context.OutgoingResponse.StatusDescription = "Your Message";
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to see the status description in the header, REST method should make sure to return null from the Catch() section as below:

```
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusDescription = ex.Message;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me either, I still get a 200. I'm using WebHttpBinding with crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" and an end point behaviour of webHttp with a default body style of wrapped and a default outgoing response format of json.. but that shouldn't matter, should it?

Answer (score 1):

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
throw new WebException("令牌码不正确", new InvalidTokenException());
```

ref:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f6671de3-34ce-4b70-9a77-39ecf5d1b9c3/weboperationcontext-http-statuses-and-exceptions?forum=wcf

Answer (score 0):

This did not work for me for WCF Data Services. Instead, you can use DataServiceException in case of Data Services. Found the following post useful.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetdataservices/thread/f0cbab98-fcd7-4248-af81-5f74b019d8de

Comment: That doesn't work for me either, I just get a 400 Bad Request, with no other useful information, and no response body.