# What is the best way to return errors from a WCF service in a RESTful way?

Tags: wcf, web-services, error-handling, rest

Using WCF in a RESTful way seems great. I’m a big fan of the big guns like simplicity and flexibility, but I also love the way the Urls end up looking. What can I say, I’m a programmer.

The simple API for retrieving and editing resources is matched by an almost equally simple set of possible error responses, and I can’t help feeling that to keep to a “pure” RESTful approach I may be cutting my nose off to spite by face, or more specifically, the nose of my web service consumers. I could be wrong, but there doesn’t seem to be very many Http error codes that I can use, and no ways to pass back a custom error message.

To clarify, I am talking about proper exceptional errors and not expected errors. I want to actually communicate a problem to the user to help them identify what they need to do to correct it.

Possible options I am considering...

1. **Just use the Http error codes** – This seem like it would be too restrictive in what I am able to express, and won’t allow me to supply a custom message. Please(!) correct me if I am wrong.
2. **Always return Http Success but return custom error objects** – Obviously the most flexible but certainly not the most RESTful.

I would really appreciate it if anyone could share some real world experience of this particular problem.

---

#### Update

Thanks for the suggestion of using the `StatusDescription` property of the `OutgoingWebResponseContext` object. It seemed at first to be something that I could use.

I have come to the conclusion that my second option above is not for me. I want to stick to the what Http can give me.

I am having problems getting it to work, however. Regardless of the value I supply for this property, it doesn’t get returned in the response.

My service method looks like this

```
public MyType GetMyTypes(string criteria)
{
    try
    {
        return GetMyTypes();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        OutgoingWebResponseContext response = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
        response.StatusDescription = "A Big fat error occurred";
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here is the raw response message. There is no mention of the custom message...

> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
> Server: ASP.NET Development Server/9.0.0.0
> Date: Wed, 07 Jan 2009 14:01:20 GMT
> X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
> Cache-Control: private
> Content-Length: 0
> Connection: Close

It's not as if I just need to access the correct property on the client. The information is simply not being sent across the link.

What does this `StatusDescription` property actually do?

---

#### Update

I never did find out how to set the StatusDescription property. I ended up not including any error message at all, and going solely with the Http status codes. I have chosen to expose both Soap and Restful endpoints for my services, and so clients can choose which they prefer to use – the simple Restful messages or the relatively richer Soap messages.

Comment: sorry, i'm out of time,
but maybe this link http://www.robbagby.com/rest/effective-error-handling-with-wcf-rest/
could be useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Send the proper response code and you can supply the custom error message in the body of the response.

Answer (score 23):

With .net 4, throw a [`WebFaultException<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd989924(v=vs.110).aspx)`(T errorDetail,` [`HttpResponseCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx)`code)`

Here you set your response type to another object type, which makes sense, and also you set the `ResponseCode` that you want.

The `errorDetail` must be serializable

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/21/error-handling-in-wcf-webhttp-services-with-webfaultexception.aspx

Comment: For me, this just causes clients to get "connection forcibly closed by host"

Answer (score 6):

I add the error code both as above (in the status description) and in the body of the returned page in my REST services as:

```
OutgoingWebResponseContext response = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
response.StatusDescription = "You are not authorized.";
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("You are not authorized.");
return null;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I could never get the StatusDescription property to actually do anything. I think I was probably doing something wrong. In the end I went for using basic statuc codes. We also expose the services at Soap endpoints and they return more meaningful messages. Our customers have the choice.

Comment: BTW, if you indent each line of your code with 4 spaces it gets formatted properly.

Comment: this doesn't work if you are using pure WCF, the HttpContext.Current is a asp.net construct.  To do it in WCF, fault = WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse("You are not authorized").

Answer (score 2):

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140104/how-can-i-return-a-custom-http-status-code-from-a-wcf-rest-method) for a similar question.

In a nutshell I believe you can set the HTTP status code (to one of the error codes), and provide your custom message in the [StatusDescription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.outgoingwebresponsecontext.statusdescription.aspx) property:

```
OutgoingWebResponseContext response = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
response.StatusDescription = "Custom";
```

I don't know much about the prevalence of this technique in the real world unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a defect. As of 9/22/2011, the issue is under review by the product team:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/690162/wcf-rest-custom-outgoingwebresponsecontext-statusdescription-not-returned-in-response