# Returning HttpStatus codes with message from WCF Rest service that IParameterInspector AfterCall can handle

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-4.0, wcf-rest

So then, I've got a number of methods in a a couple of services that I've decorated with a custom attribute.

That attribute uses the `ApplyDispatchBehavior` from `IOperationBehavior` to attach to the method and the `BeforeCall` and `AfterCall` methods from `IParameterInspector` to do some processing before and after the service method is called.

All is good, well was good...
The problem comes when the the services method needs to return a http status along with the a message.  The only way I could find to do that was for the method to throw a `WebFaultException<T>` passing in our message and the appropriate http status.

The problem with this is the attached attribute's `AfterCall` is never called.

**The long and short of it is:**

- Is there a way of returning a message
  and setting the http status without
  throwing an exception?
- If I do have to throw a `WebFaultException<T>` is there a way my attribute can still get called with the returned message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok after a lot of searching I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417632) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140104/140154#140154)

So to summarise: a call to a little method like:

```
public void SetResponseHttpStatus(HttpStatusCode statusCode)
{
    var context = WebOperationContext.Current;
    context.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = statusCode;
}
```

...before each return that isn't a plain 200 response should do it.

Comment: Interesting. I am returning Json. ContentType is application/json, however, as soon as I set the WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created (201) the ContentType switches to application/xml.