# how to return 404 not found from a wcf service?

Tags: .net, wcf, http-status-code-404

Once, to have a complete control over the head/body of HTTP messages - I use the Message class. To return some XML, for example, I call

```
  public Message ShowRunResults()
  {
    // some [OperationContract] implementation
    webContext.CreateTextResponse(result.ToString(), "application/xml", Encoding.ASCII);
  }
```

**The question** is how to return 404 not found or other HTTP codes?
thanks a lot

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I return a custom HTTP status code from a WCF REST method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140104/how-can-i-return-a-custom-http-status-code-from-a-wcf-rest-method)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse`, you can set the HTTP code and status.