# Causing HTTP error status to be returned in WCF

Tags: wcf, http, rest, http-status-codes

How can I get my WCF service to communicate errors in a RESTful manner?  Specifically, if the caller passes invalid query string parameters to my method, I'd like to have a 400 or 404 HTTP error returned to the user.  When I search for HTTP error status in relation to WCF, all I can find are pages where people are trying to *resolve* errors they're receiving.  I'd rather not just throw a `FaultException`, because that gets converted to a 500 error, which is not the correct status code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a helpful article here: http://zamd.net/2008/07/08/error-handling-with-webhttpbinding-for-ajaxjson/.  Based on that, this is what I came up with:

```
public class HttpErrorsAttribute : Attribute, IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint, 
        BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        var handlers = endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers;
        handlers.Clear();
        handlers.Add(new HttpErrorHandler());
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }

    public class HttpErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
    {
        public bool HandleError(Exception error)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void ProvideFault(
            Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
        {
            HttpStatusCode status;
            if (error is HttpException)
            {
                var httpError = error as HttpException;
                status = (HttpStatusCode)httpError.GetHttpCode();
            }
            else if (error is ArgumentException)
            {
                status = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            }
            else
            {
                status = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            }

            // return custom error code.
            fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, "", error.Message);
            fault.Properties.Add(
                HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name,
                new HttpResponseMessageProperty
                {
                    StatusCode = status,
                    StatusDescription = error.Message
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

This allows me to add a `[HttpErrors]` attribute to my service.  In my custom error handler, I can ensure that the HTTP status codes I'd like to send are sent.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using standard WCF then `FaultException` is the correct approach to this. If you do not wish to do that and you want to be RESTful then you should use the [REST WCF approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd547388) ([Here is a quick start template for 4.0](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fbc7e5c1-a0d2-41bd-9d7b-e54c845394cd/) and for [3.5](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/842a05c3-4cc8-49d3-837f-5ec7e6b17e80)). This fully supports returning HTTP Status Codes to the client.

Comment: Great link.  Unfortunately, I'm not looking for a template for creating a new service, but rather a way to add to my existing service.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to implement the same solution you are asking, the link below worked perfect when you want to play with HTTP status codes.

[How can I return a custom HTTP status code from a WCF REST method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140104/how-can-i-return-a-custom-http-status-code-from-a-wcf-rest-method)

There is a `WebOperationContext` that you can access and it has a `OutgoingResponse` property of type `OutgoingWebResponseContext` which has a `StatusCode` property that can be set.

```
WebOperationContext ctx = WebOperationContext.Current;
ctx.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
```