# Return 403 Error code from WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, http-status-code-403

I have a pretty basic RESTful WCF service in C# as follows.

```
public SchoolList[] GetSchoolList(string authenticationToken, string term, string stateID, string schoolTypes)
{
    if (!TokenAuthenticator.Authenticate(authenticationToken, out marketPlaceIdInner))
    {

        //throw new ApplicationException(Constants.InvalidAuth); //**line 1**
    }

    try
    {
        SchoolList[] returnedschoolList = schoolManagementCacheServiceClient.GetSchoolSuggestions(term, schoolTypes, stateID).ToArray<SchoolList>();
        return returnedschoolList;
    }
    finally
    {
        schoolManagementCacheServiceClient.Close();
    }
}
```

It is functioning well, what I want to achieve is when the control reaches **line 1** I want to return a simple error string and HTTP Status code to be 403 i.e. forbidden.

How can I achieve it in minimal code? I have referred other code samples and that are too big and bit complex.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314625/causing-http-error-status-to-be-returned-in-wcf ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this class
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.weboperationcontext.aspx

And this post:
[How can I return a custom HTTP status code from a WCF REST method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140104/how-can-i-return-a-custom-http-status-code-from-a-wcf-rest-method)