# Write Custom message for large request in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, rest, wcf

I limited my WCF service to allow requests up to 1 MB. This is done via binding configuration in web.config. This is working fine and client is getting 413  error code back in response. The only problem is the response body is empty. I want to include custom message in response body but I don't find a way to do it as .NET handles it automatically.

Let me know if anyone know how to add custom message in response of large requests.

Comment: consider adding more information to your question

Comment: Anyone who can't work out that a 413 response means their request was too large won't read the message anyway.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140104/how-can-i-return-a-custom-http-status-code-from-a-wcf-rest-method) one helps.

Comment: It helped but I am not sure where to write that code to throw the exception as in my case .NET/WCF throws the exception without hitting my method. The only thing I can specify in web.config is the size limit but not the handler to execute when received request is more than the specified size limit.

Comment: @user10129272: Does your service get instantiated at all? If the exception gets thrown from within your context's AppDomain, you should be able to capture the exception. It may help if you post some code, even if it doesn't appear to be getting called.

Comment: There is no code, its just WCF binding configuration you specify the max request size .                                                                        <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="myTestBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="500000" maxReceivedMessageSize="500000" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" >