# How doing the exception handling in WCF REST C#

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, exception

I have a Wcf Rest service

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]       
    void Import(stringrequest);
```

My try code:

```
 public void Import(string request)
    {
        if (request != null)
        {
             //....
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Empty DATA");
        }
    }
```

In fact, I want to display a specific error message on the else treatment,when I test my wcf srevice in POSTMAN , if I enter a empty string ---> My objectif to display "Empty DATA",

How can do that? Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle **exception** you should use [try-catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch).

When you want to handle all **possible behavior**, like empty strings or string full of numbers etc.. You can use **if-else** statement as you are doing.

You need to change your return type from `void` to `string` :

```cs
public string Import(string request) {

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(request)) {
        // ...
        return "{ \"Status\" : \"Ok\" }"; // or null if you don't want to return anything
    }
    else 
    {
        return "{ \"Status\" : \"Error : Empty DATA\" }";    
    }
}
```

You can also check this [link](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to learn more about how to use Json in C#.
[How to use http return code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140104/how-can-i-return-a-custom-http-status-code-from-a-wcf-rest-method) and [how to return Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086666/how-do-i-return-clean-json-from-a-wcf-service), that could help you understand a bit more how WCF REST works.

Hope this helps.